# Model não está sendo totalmente validado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Bom dia Pessoal, estou testando uma aplicação para adicionar um cliente, mas sempre que tento adicionar o usuário, teste o ViewModel para verificar se as informação estão coerentes, mas o programa não chega a validar todo ViewModel ignorando o final dele, saberiam por que isso está ocorrendo ?

AddClientViewModels:

```
public class TelefoneVM
{
    public String Telephone { get; set; }
}

public class EmailVM
{
    public String Email { get; set; }
}

public class AddClientViewModels : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo Pessoa")]
    public int TypePerson { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "A {0} deve ter pelo menos {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Razão Social")]
    public String CompanyName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^\([1-9]{2}\) [2-9][0-9]{3,4}\-[0-9]{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Telefone está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public List<TelefoneVM> Telephones { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "E-mail está em um formato inválido.")]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public List<EmailVM> Emails { get; set; }


    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (TypePerson == 1 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) 
            yield return new ValidationResult("Nome é obrigatório", new[] { nameof(Name) });

        if (TypePerson == 2 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyName))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Razão Social é obrigatório", new[] { nameof(CompanyName) });
    }
}
```

Essa ultima parte, ele simplesmente ignora:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (TypePerson == 1 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)) 
            yield return new ValidationResult("Nome é obrigatório", new[] { nameof(Name) });

        if (TypePerson == 2 && String.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyName))
            yield return new ValidationResult("Razão Social é obrigatório", new[] { nameof(CompanyName) });
    }
```

Dessa forma não consigo validar se o usuário é físico ou jurídico, e não consigo retornar o erro de campo obrigatório, agradeço muito se conseguirem me ajudar.

Comment: Ele só vai disparar se todas as outras validações tiverem passado, acho até dá para forcar o `Validate()`, mas não vejo muito sentido nisso.

Comment: O Problema é que ele não está sendo disparado, mesmo que todas validações tenham ocorrido, pois, digamos quando envio o campo `Nome` vazio, ele não retorna que o campo é obrigatório

Comment: O que você quer dizer com disparar? Você está olhando o `ModelState` na `Controller`?

Comment: Isso, eu envio o formulário em branco, e ele não está me retornando o erro que `O nome é obrigatário`, ele está ignorando esse erro.

Comment: Aqui está funcionando... inclua a sua action na pergunta, você está retornado a com a model? o post é ajax?

Comment: Eu descobri o problema, agora estou tentando resolver, como gero campos de telefone e email dinamicante no formulario, estou passando um model com uma lista pelo controller na hora de renderizar a tela  `model.Telephones.Add(new TelefoneVM() { Telephone = "" });` e `model.Emails.Add(new EmailVM() { Email = "" });` isso está interferindo, e não retornando os erros.

Comment: Então acho que dá para fechar essa pergunta e abrir uma nova caso encontre outra dificuldade